# Not persisting entity with thymeleaf, spting data and r2dbc

Tags: spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf, r2dbc

Im trying to create Skill entity through Thymeleaf form  and  post it:

- controller's endpoint

  ```
    @PostMapping("/add")
    public String addSkill(@ModelAttribute Skill skill){
        log.info( "  orly? "+  (skill== null));
        log.info(skill.getName() + " name  was set");
        log.info(skill.getId() + " i<--d");
        log.info(skill.getLevel() + " level  was set");
        log.info(skill.getPriority() + " prior  was set");
        log.info(skill.getSkillGroupName() + " group id  was set");
        service.add(skill);
        return TEMPLATE;
  ```

  }
- service's method

  ```
   @Override
    public Mono<Skill> add(Skill skill) {
        log.debug("SKILL IS ______ "+ skill.getName() + "  ____WAS SAVED");
        return repository.save(skill);
    }
  ```
- repo

  ```
  @Repository
  public interface SkillRepository extends ReactiveCrudRepository<Skill, UUID> {
        Mono<UUID> removeById(UUID id);
    }
  ```
- entity implements Persistable

  ```
  @Data
  @Table
  @NoArgsConstructor
  @AllArgsConstructor
  public class Skill implements Persistable<UUID> {
    @Id
    private UUID id;
    @Column("skill_name")
    private String name;
    private Level level;
    private Priority priority;
    @Column("skill_group_name")
    private String skillGroupName;

    @Override
    public boolean isNew() {
        boolean result = Objects.isNull(id);
        this.id = result ? UUID.randomUUID() : this.id;
        return result;
    }
  ```

  }

Main class is annotated with @EnableR2dbcRepositories.
When I submit form, I get the log, confirming that entity is not null, all fields but id aren't nulls. And that's all, service's method add(Skill skill) never produce logs, neither postgres shows tuple. Any ideas?

Comment: The `Mono` is never subscribed to so nothing will happen.

Comment: Huh, well. Is it a good idea to subscribe it right in controller, which basically returns string/thymeleaf template?

Comment: It works after I added .subscribe() in controller's service call. The only thing makes me confusing, that we do not propagate our reactive chain from DB till UI and cut it in controller.

Comment: You have to subscribe else nothing will happen. You could return `Mono<String>` and do something like `return service.add(skill).then(Mono.just(TEMPLATE));`. Then the result will subscribe and render the view after completion.